# What is the suggested way to write helper API for chaincode data?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

What i understand is  chaincodes are smart contracts and implement business logic and rules.It also creates  and manipulate entities/assets in shared ledger as per the business logic. But in the fabric examples, helper methods like readMarble, getAllMarblesforOwner are also implemented in chaincode. So my question is while keeping chaincodes to implement only business logic it there any other suggested way to interact with the shared ledger and write helper methods?

Answer (score 1):

Chaincode is the only interface for one to interact with the ledger it has to implement Chaincode interface:

```
type mychaincode struct {
}

func (cc *mychaincode) Init(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response {
    panic("not implemented")
}

func (cc *mychaincode) Invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response {
    panic("not implemented")
}
```

where `shim.ChaincodeStubInterface` exposes set of API's to interact with ledger such as changing the state, reading the state and many others. Of course you can to keep things more clear and nice to define auxiliary functions:

```
type mychaincode struct {
}

func (cc *mychaincode) Init(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response {
    panic("not implemented")
}

func (cc *mychaincode) Invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response {
    function, args := stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()

    if args['0'] == "aux" {
        // Call aux function
        cc.auxFunction(args)
    }
}

func (cc *mychaincode) auxFunction(someparameters interface{}) {
    // Do some very important logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a scoping rule regarding to accessing data: any piece of data (key-value pair) created by a chaincode may only be accessible to that chaincode. So the chaincode determines who may read and write its data and provides proper access control.

To interact with the ledger structure, such as traversing blocks and transactions, there is a system chaincode called [qscc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyperledger-fabric) (query system chaincode), which provides ability to query information on channels, blocks and transactions.

From information modeling point of view, you may use multiple chaincodes, each may be responsible for managing certain part(s), and some would provide aggregation. For example, to model a car engine (disclaimer: I have no background in auto mechanics), you might want EngineChaincode, CylinderChaincode, SparkplugChaincode, OilSumpChaincode, etc. EngineChaincode would call other chaincodes to aggregate information on query.